# Вывод характеристик файлов Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Есть командный файл для вывода всех файлов с запрашиваемым расширением и именем, но у меня ошибка выводит только первый файл, и при выводе пишет ошибка синтаксиса

```
@echo off
echo Output file name and characteristics
if "%1"=="" (
echo Do not specify the 1st parameter
echo Input /? to output help
pause
goto :EOF
)
if "%1"=="/?" (
echo Output file name and characteristics
echo 1st parameter - folder name
echo 2nd parameter - file type
echo Types:
echo -text for *.txt
echo -command for *.bat
echo -all for *.*
pause
goto exit
)
if not exist %1 (
echo Folder is not exist
pause
goto exit
)
if not "%1"=="." (
pushd %1
)
if "%2"=="" (
echo Do not specify the 2nd parameter
set /p nam=Input file name:
set /p ext=Input file extension:
) else (goto run)
if not exist "*.%ext%" (
echo There are not *.%ext% files in this folder
pause
goto exit
) else (goto user_type)
:run
if "%2"=="text" (
for %%I in (*.txt) do call :attrib1 "%%I" .txt
pause
goto exit
)
if "%2"=="command" (
for %%I in (*.bat) do call :attrib1 "%%I" .bat
pause
goto exit
)
if "%2"=="all" (
for %%I in ("*.*") do call :attrib1 "%%I" %%~xI
pause
goto exit
)
:user_type
for %%I in (%nam%.%ext%) do call :attrib1 "%%I" .%ext%
pause
goto exit
pause
goto :exit
:attrib1
echo Output file name and characteristics for file %1
attrib %1
echo End
exit /b
:exit
if not "%1"=="." (cd ../)
```

[image: Консоль]

Comment: Мне кажется, проблема в том, что Вы используете парсер **for** для разбора значений получаемых ИЗ текстового файла, а нужно обрабатывать файл (его АТРИБУТЫ), а не его содержимое. Для этого есть встроенная утилита **FORFILES**

Comment: @Daemon-5 Можете привести пример пожалуйста

Comment: **forfiles /p "C:\Users\Aleks\Documents" /m *.txt /c "cmd /c attrib @file"** или в Вашем случае **forfiles /p "%1" /m *.%2 /c "cmd /c attrib @file"**